# How to send a keystroke to a minimized window in X11?

Tags: linux, x11, xdotool

I'm trying to trigger a keyboard shortcut to the linux Anki app, but `xdotool search --class "Anki"` returns 17 window IDs. Sending the shortcut to one of these *does* work, but using the others gives a list of errors. Is there a way to just get the "correct" window? (and why are there many anyway?)

(A partial solution was to search with `onlyvisible`: `xdotool search --onlyvisible --class "Anki"`, but this requires the window not to be minimized.)

Comment: Why don't you just use --name with a full window name?

Comment: @nsilent22 the window name is "Anki" and when searching with `--name` instead of `--class` I still get the same list of window IDs, i.e there seems to be many windows with that name.